# How to specify no ri/rdoc exists for a gem so user doesn't get warning when trying to install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rdoc

A gem I'm authoring doesn't have any inline ri/rdoc of any kind, so when users `gem install` it they get warnings when rubygems tries to compile the docs:

```
Successfully installed mygem-0.0.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mygem-0.0.1...
File not found: lib
```

I'm assuming this is due to it trying to run the ri tool against my app's lib folder which doesn't exist (gem is all binaries). How can I avoid this error? I tried placing dummy files in `lib/` but that didn't help.

Comment: Which toolset are you using to build the gem?

Comment: What are the settings of `has_rdoc`, `rdoc_options`, `rdoc_files` and `extra_rdoc_files` in your `.gemspec`?

Comment: I was using Jeweler. Only the basic options are set; none of those you mentioned. I'll look through the gemspec options now.

Comment: `has_rdoc` is unset but should default to false so that should be fine. I set it explicitly to false just in case. I still get the message when it tries to build the ri though... is there no `has_ri` option anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there was actually a confusion of issues on this question. I mistakenly assumed the error message about `lib` was associated with the message before it about the ri install.

This was not the case. The problem was that the default `require_paths` is `["lib"]` which my gem did not have. Resetting the `require_paths` in my gemspec eliminated the error.